# GrabCut cannot work in my code and I do not know to change the code

Tags: python, opencv, foreground

I want to  find the foreground of a picture using Grabcut, below is the code

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

img=cv2.imread(r'D:\Python Code\Grabcut\fqx.jpg')
cv2.imshow('src',img)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)


rect=(155,1,367,640)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but the result is not perfect:

[image]

so i imitate the 'Interactive Foreground Extraction using GrabCut Algorithm' from the official website of Opencv, the code is below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

img=cv2.imread(r'D:\Python Code\Grabcut\fqx.jpg')
cv2.imshow('src',img)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)


rect=(155,1,367,640)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
#plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
cv2.imshow('img',img)
# newmask is the mask image I manually labelled
newmask = cv2.imread(r'D:\Python Code\Grabcut\newmark.jpg',0)
# whereever it is marked white (sure foreground), change mask=1
# whereever it is marked black (sure background), change mask=0
mask[newmask == 0] = 0
mask[newmask == 255] = 1
mask, bgdModel, fgdModel =             
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,None,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
mask = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and the newmask is that

[image]

and the there is a problem, after run the code, it comes TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. I change the parameter of 'None' but it still can not work.

Comment: https://pythonprogramming.net/grabcut-foreground-extraction-python-opencv-tutorial/

Comment: do you know how i do it in java? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978380/how-to-remove-the-background-of-the-image-of-interest-using-opencv-on-android