# How to remove the background of the image of interest using opencv on android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin

I'm working with opencv for android studio. I have little experience with this, so I am asking for help to remove the background from the image and leave only the region of interest. I am working with images of wounds and I want to leave only the region of the wound on the application screen, as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am working with kotlin and I managed to perform the watershed of the image, just missing the region of the wound from the backgroung of the image, can someone help me?

```
private fun threashold(){

    val width = imgBmpDefault?.getWidth()!!
    val height = imgBmpDefault?.getHeight()!!
    val rgba = Mat()
    val gray_mat = Mat()
    val threeChannel = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(imgBmpDefault, gray_mat)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray_mat, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, threeChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    Imgproc.threshold(threeChannel, threeChannel, 100.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU)
    val fg = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    Imgproc.erode(threeChannel, fg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 2)
    val bg = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    Imgproc.dilate(threeChannel, bg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 3)
    Imgproc.threshold(bg, bg, 1.0, 128.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    val markers = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(0.0))
    Core.add(fg, bg, markers)

    val marker_tempo = Mat()
    markers.convertTo(marker_tempo, CvType.CV_32S)

    Imgproc.watershed(rgba, marker_tempo)
    marker_tempo.convertTo(markers, CvType.CV_8U)

    imgBmpExit = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565)

    Imgproc.applyColorMap(markers, markers, 4)
    Utils.matToBitmap(markers, imgBmpExit)

    imagem.setImageBitmap(imgBmpExit)

}
```

Exit using other image of wound:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some input (and intermediate) images; else it is too hard to give specific advice.

Comment: @RobAu I managed to evolve the code and asked a new question with updates. Can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed